# Electronic drum set powered with batteries

Tags: power-supply, batteries

I have a electronic drum set that I want to make portable . Is it safe to use couple of parallel joined 9v 500 mA batteries to replace the 9v, 500 mA  AC adapter and could the batteries last for couple of hours? The drum set is consisted of total 7 elemens plus a simple controlling device.the connecting cablels are relatively long, total of cca 4,5 meters..

Answer (score 3):

> Is it safe to use couple of parallel joined 9v 500 mA batteries ...

Batteries are rated in **mAh** - not mA. If they are 900 mAh then they can (ideally) provide 900 mA for one hour or, more likely, 90 mA for 10 hours with somewhat less at higher discharge rates.

To estimate run time you need to measure the current drawn by your drum set. To do this you need to somehow wire a multimeter on DC amps range **in series** with the power supply. You can estimate your battery run time by \$ h = \frac {battery\;rating}{meter\;reading} \$ where h is hours.

You can parallel the batteries if they are the same type.

Comment: As a side note, most batteries also have a maximum load current rating. This should be at least 500mA in this scenario.

Answer (score 2):

DC is not AC

> Is it safe to use couple of parallel joined 9v 500 mA batteries to
>   replace the 9v, 500 mA **AC** adapter

It's an AC adapter and batteries produce DC so, without a full examination of the schematic, no.

9 volt AC peaks at 12.7 volts and may indeed be used to generate + and - internal voltage rails of +12 volts and - 12 volts using half wave rectifiers. This won't happen with a DC battery of course,

It's irrelevant asking about battery life because batteries should not be used to power this piece of equipment without a thorough examination of the circuitry.

Comment: +1 for AC part, though, I find folks use the AC adapter definition a bit loosely. OP needs to confirm it's AC-AC or actually AC-DC. ( both of those are technically AC adapters...)

Answer (score 0):

If you take another look at your AC adapter, it should tell you Its  specifications I.E. 120 volt AC, and then it says what it provides which is 9 volts, 500 mA, but it will also say whether it is AC or 9 volts of DC power. Many appliances use DC.  If it is DC, then I recommend that you use 6 - AA batteries in series - the positive connected to the negative etc of each successive battery.  You would still get the 9 volts AND you would get closer to 2500 mAh or 5 hours of play time.  You can find battery holders that will hold the 6 batteries togetherness in series for you making this a very simple project.  If you really want to get crazy, apparently Energizer D sized battery will give you 20,000 mAh, so 6 of them in series will let you drum until you get tendinitis!

The 9 volt 'square' battery is designed for low power products, more like <100 mA or you get serious voltage drop, so it is just not a great choice for your setup, assuming you even need DC.

Good luck